# Texturing Fractured Objects

Tags: texturing

How do you apply UV mapping and texturing to an object after it has been fractured? If I texture things before I fracture it, things mess up (A bug in blender right now) but if I wait to texture the object until after I fracture it, as far as I know right now I am forced to deal with each separate object one at a time causing not only a headache because of how long it takes, but when I do texturing like this, the texture doesn't line up properly from object to object.

Comment: Are you using the fracture modifier or the cell fracture addon. I think the fracture modifier is beyond the scope of this site but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could use Object texturing, note that it might change the UV's as the fractured mesh moves.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I'm using the Cell Fracture add on.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise would using object texturing get the inside faces as well?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, however it may change when it moves. It is worth a try

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise do you know of a good tutorial for Object texturing?

Comment: you can use object or generated texture coordinates for basic texturing. else check : http://cgcookie.com/blender?s=texturing&s_type=tutorials

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Scorpion 81's fracture modifier build instead of Blender's default cell fracture. There, the fracture is a modifier, so you can unwrap and apply your material to a cube, and after fracturing each piece of the fracture will retain it's original uv coordinates. In addition, Scorpion 81's fracture modifier build offers some great features for streamlining and making easier the fracturing process.

Here is a link to an example of the modifier in action:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Vcd1GQw5Ac

Here is the fracture modifier build's page:
http://df-vfx.de/fracturemodifier/

Comment: If I use Scorpion81, will I be able to texture the insides of the fractured objects and will the objects work the same way with ridged bodies?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and couldn't find the way I solved it online, so I thought I would post my findings.

I had a simple cube mesh - many people said there would be no issue without a complex shape. I found that a new cube would cell fracture perfectly - yet after a resize and texture I would get the same problem.

Turned out it was related to the scale of my item. After making the adjustments, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and setting the size changes (making the scale 1,1,1 again) it all seemed to work perfect.

If the scale of an object is not 1,1,1 then I get the problem. Applying the scale changes fixes it.

Comment: Hey Michael, I edited your post to make it a bit less conversational. We try to keep posts here more focused on the answer itself, and less on how you arrived at that answer, since that tends to be more helpful for future readers. Thanks for the answer and welcome to the site!